# Can two Azure web applications use the same token for authentication?

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I've got a SPA application and an associated API from which it gets its data.  (Aurelia and Nodejs)

I have recently worked out the Authentication on the SPA so that it uses MSAL to authenticate users against our company's AAD and is able to retrieve a token that the app can then use to access the MS Graph as well.

However, I also want my API to authenticate against the AAD.  What I'd like is for the API to be able to accept the token from the SPA client.

While I am able to send the token from the client to the API (`Authorization: 'Bearer'...)` **I'm not sure what to do with it on the server side to then verify with the identity provider that the token is valid.**

For the most part, I don't want the API to have UI concerns (i.e. an authentication/login screen).  It should simply reject any requests that do not carry the correct token.

I hope to eventually have both client and server apps being hosted as App Services on Azure, but for the time being they are hosted internally.  I think there is a way to ensure the solution works regardless of where the apps are hosted.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the relationship between the title and the body of the question: I will answer the body :)
In https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/ you can see an example of web API token validation in Node JS. The service side logic just needs to be adjusted to point to the Azure AD tenant you are using.
The above will work regardless of where the API is hosted, given that the parameters being validated are all about logical identifiers.

Comment: The link you gave talks about registering the application.  I'm getting confused with that term.  I can register an app in my tenant but there is also an Azure App registration portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) that is referenced in quite a few different documents and examples.  How does one know which place to register an application?

Comment: I linked to the sample so that you could check out the token validation code in node js, I wasn't suggesting you should change your registration settings at all. If you are using MSAL and invoking the graph as described in your question, I assume you registered your app in apps.dev.microsoft.com; you should not need to change anything in that respect.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still trying to get my mind wrapped around all of this, but I think your sample is helping to get me there.